# Convex subsets of Hadamard manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Given a subset $S$ of a [Hadamard manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_manifold) $M$. Is there a curvature criterion (for $\partial S$) to decide whether $S$ is convex.

I am looking for a ganeralization of the following statement:

A connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded by a smooth curve $\gamma$ with $||\dot{\gamma}||=1$  is convex, if $\gamma$ "always turns in the same direction" - more formally if $t\mapsto det(\dot{\gamma}(t),\ddot{\gamma}(t))$ never changes sign.

Comment: I believe that the appropriate generalization is a positive semidefinite second fundamental form.

Comment: @Henrik: Can you specify what you consider a *convex* subset of a Riemannian manifold?

Comment: convex for me means geodesically convex. is there another reasonable meaning?

Comment: In Hadamard manifolds there is a unique geodesic between any two points so convexity can only mean geodesic convexity. 

Comment: Thank you. After some googling I found the paper "Locally convex hypersurfaces of negatively curved spaces" by S. Alexander (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-064-02/S0002-9939-1977-0448262-6/S0002-9939-1977-0448262-6.pdf), which adresses precisely this question.

Comment: @Henrik: perhaps you may want to re-post your last comment as a CW-answer and accept it. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. After some googling I found the paper "Locally convex hypersurfaces of negatively curved spaces" by S. Alexander (ams.org/journals/proc/1977-064-02/…), which adresses precisely this question.